# ajax / json output must be an other format

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Hi for an jquery map I get the values over ajax. The format for the map must be 
`var new_sample_data = {"af":"16.63","al":"11.58","dz":"158.97",...};`.

I have tested it with var `new_sample_data = {"af":16.63,...};` and all works good. But If I take it over jason. It doesn't work. What I must change?

The php testcode:

```
$sample_data[] = array("de","$de");

echo json_encode($sample_data);
```

The javascript code:

```
        $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",                                    
        url: '../mail/assets/includes/geodata1.php',
        data: {datum1: Date.today().add({days: -29}).toString('yyyy-MM-dd'), datum2: Date.today().toString('yyyy-MM-dd')},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
        var new_sample_data = data;
```

In Firebug I see the response is `[["de","4"]]`. But how I can change it to the format the map need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an **associative array** in PHP:

`$sample_data = array("de"=>"$de");`

Then encoding it should result in a proper JSON String that can be parsed into a JavaScript Object.

To see the proper content of `new_sample_data` in JavaScript, use `console.dir(new_sample_data);`, it will list the object's attributes.

You can access the value of your new attribute this way in JavaScript:

`console.log(new_sample_data.de);`

Answer (score 1):

Your php array should set the index of de to the variable like such:

```
$sample_data[] = array("de" => "$de");
```

That wasy $sample_data["de"] will = "$de";

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I have changed it. Now firebug says: [{"de":"4"}]. But it still not work. I have insert an alert of new_sample_data there now I get "[object Object]".

Comment: Yes, then you can access it via `var new_sample_data = data[0];`

Comment: @verbanicm: But why wrap the assoc-array/object in a pointless array, which issues notices anyway? just assigning the array would be _much_ better

Comment: Oops, that was my bad i didnt notice the array brackets on the left.... `$sample_data = array("de" => "$de");` and use this in the JS `var new_sample_data = data;`

Answer (score 0):

$sample_data['de'] = $de;

it will work as you expected

Comment: And I expect it'll issue a warning, still. Please, initializing/declaring variables isn't just for show. Using an uninitialized var as an array will work, but it issues notices, even if you suppress them, they are still being produced. A lot of them slow your code down

Comment: is there any difference between $sample_data = array("de" => $de); and $sample_data['de'] = $de;? both are same.

Comment: Yes there's a difference. `$sample_data = array();` declares a variable, and assigns an array to it. `$sample_data['de'] = $de` implies that `$sample_data` was allready assigned an array. If `$sample_data` doesn't exist, PHP will create an array for you (but a notice will be issued). If `$sample_data` already exists as, for example, a string, you'll get an error. Either way: notices are bad, errors are terrible, and they're easily avoided in this case

Comment: If you want to check how many warnings code like yours generates, just set your php.ini error reporting to `E_STRICT | E_ALL`, like I said in my answer. BTW: your goal should be to write warning-free code, so set your error_reporting to the strictest possible setting, always (except for production environment)